# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not working when change constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `costView` which holds `UILabel dollarSign` and `UILabel cost`. [This is how `dollarSign` is being constrained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDbhe.png) [This is how `cost` is being constrained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXcAQ.png)

In the `AddViewController` I changed some of the constraints, including the height of the `costView`

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var costView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var statusBarHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!
@IBOutlet weak var dollarSign: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cost: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var keyboardHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var costViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set size of cost view & numbers keyboard
    let halfViewHeight = (view.bounds.height - statusBarHeight.constant - navigationBar.bounds.height)/2
    costViewHeight.constant = halfViewHeight/CGFloat(4)
    keyboardHeight.constant = halfViewHeight - costViewHeight.constant

    //Adjust font size of dollar sign & cost
    cost.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    print("cost frame: \(cost.frame)")
    dollarSign.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    print("dollar sign frame: \(dollarSign.frame)")
}
}
```

When I load the app, the constraints `costViewHeight` & `keyboardHeight` update and rearrange themselves accordingly. However, the font size of the labels `dollarSign` and `cost` do not adjust themselves, [as you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmdSX.png)

After adding the 2 lines in here:

```
    //Adjust font size of dollar sign & cost
    cost.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cost.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //add this line
    print("cost frame: \(cost.frame)")
    dollarSign.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    dollarSign.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //add this line
    print("dollar sign frame: \(dollarSign.frame)")
```

[You can see the frame of `cost` and `dollarSign` readjust themselves to fit in with the new constraints.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVEvG.png)

**Question:** Since I used `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`, why isn't the font size changing after I change the height? Does `.adjustFontSizeToFitWidth` only work when you change the width? If so, how can I make a `.adjustFontSizeToFitHeight` method?

A strange thing I noticed that may or not be relevant is when I printed out the `cost` and `dollarSign` frames they were exactly the same as the frames listed on the storyboard ([`cost` frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHFuX.png) and [`dollarSign` frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ7MF.png)).

```
cost frame: (567.0, 7.5, 14.5, 34.0)
dollar sign frame: (8.0, 8.0, 15.0, 34.0)
```

This is strange b/c since I changed the height of `costView` the frames of `cost` and `dollarSign` should change([which they do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVEvG.png)). But if the `cost` and `dollarSign` frame changes then why don't their numbers change?